# Recordsetclone loop

Tags: ms-access, vba

The code below works BUT only to the first record in the continuous form its not looping threw the records. So if the first record is checked then I get the message "You need to select a RELEASE check box before proceeding." and if its not I get the other message.

What I need it to do is run down all the check boxes which is "ReleaseProduct" and exit sub at the first one it reaches if there is one and give a message and  and if there isn't any check boxes checked run the Cancel = fncRequiredReleaseSelectedEmail(Me) and exit sub. Im messing up the loop somewhere...

Here is the code I have in my forms button....

```
    Dim Cancel As Integer
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = Me.frmsub_ProductHoldData.Form.RecordsetClone
With rs
    .MoveFirst
    Do While Not .EOF
        If rs.Fields("ReleaseProduct") = False Then
            MsgBox "You need to select a RELEASE check box before proceeding.", vbInformation, "Selection Error"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Cancel = fncRequiredReleaseSelectedEmail(Me)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: You have `Exit Sub` in both `If` conditions.  It will never do more than one pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a hard time telling if this is exactly what you are looking for or not but this will look through all those records and only take action if one is checked.

The warning about selecting a Release check box only shows up if no boxes are checked.

```
Dim Cancel As Integer
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = Me.frmsub_ProductHoldData.Form.RecordsetClone
With rs
    .MoveFirst
    Do While Not .EOF
        If rs.Fields("ReleaseProduct") = True Then
            Cancel = fncRequiredReleaseSelectedEmail(Me)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    MsgBox "You need to select a RELEASE check box before proceeding.", vbInformation, "Selection Error"
End With
```